# loading unstructured file in ssis

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have file from customer to load using SSIS. the file is like below

```
input file:    
dept=100;Atlanta;company_20
dept_desc=Autos
prod1; prodID1,prodprice1;prodcode1;
prod2; prodID2,prodprice2;prodcode2;
dept=200;Atlanta;company_20
dept_desc=Juices
```

I have to load above file in a table in the following format
output:

```
dept dept_desc region    companyNo  prod     Prodid   ProdPrice      Prodcode
100   Autos     Atlanta    20        prod1    prodid1   prodprice1    prodcode1
100   Autos     Atlanta    20        prod2    prodid2   prodprice2    prodcode2
```

I'm using SSIS script component (c#) to format file but not able to concatenate department information to below lines. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not? Also, should your sample data have `Autos` and not `auto`?

Comment: yes, it should have Autos not Auto.

Comment: A script task can certainly do it.   Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: You say "*..but not able to concatenate department information to below lines.*" It is not clear what you mean by this.  Please explain this more.

Comment: Or, alternatively, show us what you already have in the script task.